# Ambiguous Reference inline error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

got something here that’s driving me mad.

Using Xamarin Studio 6 (Stable) on OS X, El Capitan.

Started a new Xamarin.Forms project. My view (aptly named MyView) has a ListView in it, with a reference of x:Name=“myListView”.

When trying to access it from the code-behind, I’m getting an inline error

> “Error: Ambiguity between MyView.myListView and MyView.myListView”,

and the same thing with InitializeComponent() in every view ever.

The error doesn’t actually break anything, but destroys any intellisense capabilities and, most importantly, is incredibly annoying.

I’m assuming it’s because of the files generated behind the scenes, but not quite sure what to do about it - Google doesn’t seem to be incredibly helpful with the issue. Probably should have used Bing.

And yes, I’ve tried the clean + rebuild approach before anyone asks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and didn't find a simple awnser. As a workaround, I changed the **x:name** of the **Entry**:

From:

```
<Entry x:Name="userName" Placeholder="Username" />
```

To:

```
<Entry x:Name="userLogin" Placeholder="Username" />
```

It's not a solution, but works for now. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after updating Xamarin.forms to 3.....
The fix for me was to remove the platform specific configurations in my BaseContentpage.cs

```
**remove:** using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
```